# Journey builder API Event - Sending Multiple Emails to a Customer

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I wanted to check regarding Journey Entry using API EVENT as an entry source) - so If we use API Event from Journey builder to initiate Journey, we should not use contactkey as a primary key in our Event Data Extension otherwise we can only send one email to our contact if we try to send 2nd time it is giving duplicate subscribers error, please let me know your thoughts on this ?

Also do we really need to configure/link this Event-DE which we are using to capture Data API Event in Contact builder data designer as Contact Model ? linking the Event-DE in Contact Model in Data Designer of contact  builder give less flexibility to modify changes in Event DE , also there are chances that we may impact Journey in the future if any modification required.

As far as I know adding Journey builder entry source (Data Extension) in Contact model in data designer is the best practice ?

Please share your thought on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1)

When building API Entry sources, it is indeed your own responsibility to match the DE's Primary Key to your re-entry concept.

If the same Contact should be pushed into the journey multiple times, then  ContactKey as the sole Primary Key will lead to API errors about duplicate ContactKeys. Having this would equal the Journey setting "re-entry never".

So:
If you want to have only as a temporary block ("re-entry after exiting") then keep ContactKey as Primary Key, but give your DE a Data Retention time, so that Contacts disappear from the DE automatically and then are free to re-enter again.

If you want the equivalent to "re-enter anytime" you need a different Primary Key setup. General note: Do not create a data extension without Primary Key / PK, as this takes away flexibility (e.g. no PK, no UI search).

So: You still want to have Contactkey as ONE primary Key, as you will e.g. be able to use it for searching on the UI.

So, make a second field also Primary Key, give it a name like `rowkey`.

a) If you are flexible with your API integration, make it text, and create a GUID (length 36 char) or a UNIX timestamp  (length 10 char) externally, so that you push a unique ID into this field - GUID being the cleaner option.

b) if you CAN NOT in any way achieve a), make `rowkey` a date field, and set defaultValue: current date. I would call this a workaround with a messy key, but will be pretty much(tm) unique and functional.

Downsides to this: same-millisecond api calls could lead to errors - it shares this problem with the UNIX timestamp and it's probably negligible.

The date-field key is "messier" than UNIX timestamp because on the UI, SFMC does all sorts of masking with date fields, so from the UI you don't actually know what it really looks like, in exports it will look different again, it has a weird timezone (UTC-6) that nobody would expect or cares about, while UNIX timestamps are at least defined to UTC. So basically, just don't set this stuff up with date fields if you don't really have to.

Question 2)

There is no inherent need to tie your Event DE to the contact model. Doing this this is not a generic "best practice", but serves a specific purpose:

Mainly (there are other, more obscure side effects) you'd connect it to use the data inside it in Journey Decision splits based on Contact Data.

Sounds great, why is it then not necessary by default? Because you can always base Decision splits on Journey Data, which is exactly the data in your Entry Source DE.

If you don't know the difference between Journey and Contact Data, read this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Hi @Jonas , Thank you for detailed explanation , Could you please let me know what is the exact UI search which is you have mentioned and for that Primary key is required ? FYI - we are going to use this journey to send Service emails , and further to update CRM.   do we still need that Primary Key ? Also when we create Triggered send (using triggered send DE  template) system generated DE does not have primary key.

Comment: Login to Marketing Cloud, Contact Builder, open your DE, check what fields can be used for searching rows. You will see only the Primary Keys. About your other questions: the logic that the table setup follows is determined by your desired re-entry scenario - the business case provides no other relevant information once that is clear. You CAN set up your DE without primary keys as well like the template, but it's never bad to have PKs (UI search, PKs are indexed which increase pserformance in SQL, PKs are required for many import / sql operations).